# can not gracefully stop the application in docker

Tags: docker

In my `docker-entrypoint.sh` I had below commands:

```
check_log /logs/app.log &  # monitor the logs of application and send some statistics 
exec /bin/app "@"
```

In my docker-file, it was like this

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["dc", "-exec"]
```

because of this setup, my app was always as PID 1 and check_log as PID 2 inside the container.
During some investigation, we found that when SIGTERM command sends to the docker-container to stop the container, some of the logs from the check_logs didn't parse the logfile properly and we are missing some last moment statistics events from the logfile.

Hence I decided to use [dumb-init](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init) in my docker file. so that when I receive the SIGTERM command, I will stop the app gracefully and wait for 5mins to make sure that `check_log` sends all the logs.

So, in my `docker-entrypoint.sh` now looks like this:

```
sigterm_handler(){
    echo "${FINAL_FORMAT} sigterm handler called"
    pid=$(ps aux | grep app | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}')
    echo "PID is ${streamset_pid}"
    kill  "$streamset_pid"
    wait 10
    check_logs
    kill check_logs_pid
}

trap sigterm_handler SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGHUP SIGTERM

/bin/app "@"

# wait forever
while true
do
  tail -f /dev/null & wait ${!}
done
```

And my docker file looks like this:

```
#ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dumb-init", "--"] # tried this 
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dumb-init", "--rewrite", "15:3", "--"] #trying this
CMD ["/docker-entrypoint.sh", "dc", "-exec"]
```

Now, when I issue `docker stop <conatinerid>`, it does print the PID and kill the PID but however the container also stops there and doesn't wait for 2nd process to complete. it shows `wait: pid 10 is not a child of this shell`

How to make sure that after killing the app the container will be still running? and I think `wait forever` block is not working.

Comment: Can you restructure this so that the log files are written to a Docker volume or other shared directory, and your `check_log` script runs in another container?

Comment: @DavidMaze Sorry due to the nature of the project and cost not allowed to use the volume but I can try `check_log` in a separate container like side-car.